# What's a Capfile? And how do I use it correctly with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a ruby on rails application that should be transferred from one server to another (that's not working fine at the moment). I installed capistrano. I'm using debian 7 server with apache passenger.

I saw a `Capfile` in the root directory of the ruby on rails application.
Is a Capfile something like a makefile to build and deploy the application? How do I correctly work with it?

**UPDATE**

When I run the cap file i got this: ' cap deploy:setup '

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/deploy
/var/www/myapplication/Capfile:3:in `load'
/var/www/myapplication/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

it seems like the deploy file coun't be loaded ... i have in the config folder an deploy folder and a deploy.rb

whats going wrong?

Comment: capistrano is used to deploy the application.   The Capfile (along with config/deploy*  )  contains instructions that tell capistrano how to deploy your application to the various servers that it requires.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thought and hoped :) ... but how can I run the Capfile?

Comment: if you have cabistrano installed, it should be as simple as `cap {stage} {action}`, but this depends upon which version of capistrano you have installed (2 vs 3, etc..).  If you are feeling really brave you can try  `cap production deploy`  which would follow the recipe(s) in `config/deploy.rb` , `config/deploy/production.rb`

Comment: thanks for your help. I've updated my question above with some new queststions :)

Comment: okay this error comes from the wrong capistrano version.

Comment: @Doon Your comments could also be a (very good) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Capistrano tasks are now Rake tasks and Rake expects a construct like this:

```
task :name, [:arg, :arg] => :dependency do
  ...
end
```

Capistrano 3:

```
task :dump do
  on primary roles :db do
    ...
  end
end
```